# Getting 1 array from nested array and store into react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

New react enthusiast here needing a little bit of help.

So I have this set of array store in a state called **projects**

```
0:{id: 1, title: "Business Web", category: "Web Design", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
1:{id: 2, title: "Social App", category: "Mobile Development", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
2:{id: 3, title: "Ecommerce", category: "Web Development", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
3:{id: 4, title: "1", category: "1", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
4:{id: 5, title: "123123", category: "123123", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
5:{id: 6, title: "new", category: "new", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
6:{id: 7, title: "sdasd", category: "sdawd", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
7:{id: 8, title: "sssss", category: "ssssss", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
8:{id: 9, title: "Irene", category: "Bae", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
9:{id: 10, title: "sssss", category: "sssss", deleted_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
```

And Im using this to this to store an item into state called **projectItem**

```
this.setState({
   projectItem: this.state.projects.filter(p => p.id === id)
})﻿
```

which give me a result of something like this..

> 0: {id: 1, title: "Business Web", category: "Web Design", deleted_at:
>   "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}

Now when I try to access this state and set it as initial value for input, its not working. I set value like this

```
value={this.state.projectItem.title}
```

Can you please help me where did I go wrong? Or am I doing this the wrong way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you actually storing your filtered element into setState, or are you just assuming that's what's happening? What error are you getting? Where is id coming from? This is not a complete example.

Comment: Actually I dont get any errors. And yes its storing in the projectItem state but I cant access the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array, so to get an item you may do something like

```
cont filtered = this.state.projects.filter(p => p.id === id);
this.setState({
  projectItem: filtered.length ? filtered[0] : null
});
```

Maybe you want to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) item instead:

```
this.setState({
  projectItem: this.state.projects.find(p => p.id === id);
});
```

Comment: Wow. That works like a charm. Can you explain to me how this works? and where did I go wrong? Anyways thanks kind sir.

Comment: @SonsonIxon Just use `find` instead of `filter`. I updated the answer with the links to MDN, which can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that filter returns an array and not a single object.

Try assigning

```
this.setState(
    projectItem: this.state.projects.filter(p => p.id === id)[0]
})﻿
```

Comment: Wow. This works too. I have search how to flatten an array but none of it works. This is amazing.

Comment: You don't need to flatten an array, you need the content of the array item to be assigned to the value on the input tag. In your original code you assign the array itself as the value of the attribute